# Sleep doesn't have any effect when iterating over a string to simulate typing

Tags: perl

I want to make a script which will type string letters one by one

```
my $str = 'Test String';
my @spl = split '',$str;
for (@spl){
    print "$_";
    sleep(1);
}
print "\n";
```

`sleep()` doesn't do it's job! it makes me wait more than 1 second and im getting the full text immediately without any delay.

Comment: Sleep may not take a full second - [read the manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, you are only outputting 2 items. There is also the fact that your output may be buffered and therefore the buffer may only be flushed and printed when the `\n` gets sent.

Try setting `$|` to a non-zero value which may disable the line buffering.

e.g

```
$| = 1; 
$|++; // alternative often seen
```

Alternatively, this does the same thing:

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);    # Needs "use IO::Handle;" on older versions of Perl
```

Although probably not the issue here,`sleep()` is not a good way of waiting for a second, especially on older systems. As the [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) states, there are reasons why sleep may take less than or more than 1 second.

Comment: In this case, the `sleep(1)` call is probably taking very close to 1 second to execute. It's a perfectly good way to wait on modern systems. It's the output buffering that's the problem here.

Comment: Agreed I've edited my answer to downplay that aspect a little, but I still think it should be mentioned.

Comment: I'd have upvoted this one if you'd used the more modern and instantly more understandable `STDOUT->autoflush(1)`; try to use that one instead.

Comment: @LeoNerd TMTOWTDI - must stop entering obfuscated PERL competitions :-)

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush();
```

before printing, to disable output buffering (and thus waiting to fill buffer first).

Answer (score 2):

**You are [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)**.  The link provided takes you to an excellent article from The Perl Journal circa 1998 from Marc Jason Dominus (the author of Higher-Order Perl).  The article may be over a decade old, but the topic is as relevant today as it was when he wrote it.

In your case you need to do

```
{
    local $| = 1;
    for (@spl){
         print "$_";
         sleep(1);
    }
}
```

or use `IO::Handle` as mpapec suggested.